# LaTeX: creating new section headings

Tags: latex

I want to create a new section like heading using a custom global counter.
The intended behaviour is to have a \rule command which defines a rule, that can be used in several sections and subsection, but uses a custom global counter.

Example:

```
1. Section
1.1 SubSection
Rule 1: bla
Rule 2: foo
2. Section
Rule 3: foobar
2.1 subsection
Rule 4: yet another one
```

I tried two different things:

1.) create a custom command from scratch

```
\newcounter{rule}
\addtocounter{rule}{0} % set them to some other numbers than 0
\renewcommand{\rule}[1]{{\noindent\normalfont\Large\bfseries{Rule \arabic{rule}: 
#1 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Rule \arabic{rule}: #1}\newline\stepcounter{rule}}}}
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to format the heading so that it behaves like a section. Especially when the line gets wrapped.

Should be:

```
Rule 1: very long header line
        correctly wrapped
```

but it looks like this:

```
Rule 1: very long header line
correctly wrapped
```

Also the space between heading and the following text is something that should be configured correctly.

2.) I tried to change subsection for my use.

```
\renewcommand{\rule}[1]{\subsection{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Rule \arabic{subsection}:}
```

This is easy and works, but has obviously several drawbacks:

- the counter gets reset for each new section, so it's not a global counter.
- I cannot use subsections anymore

I think only the first option is the way to go, but I don't know how.
I hope anybody can help here.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't redefine `\rule`, as it forms an integral part of other core (La)TeX functionality. Rather use something like `\Rule`.

Here's a straight-forward implementation for your requirements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Rule{\@startsection {Rule}{1}{\z@}%
                                {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand{\Rulemark}[1]{}
\newcounter{Rule}
\let\l@Rule\l@section
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\Rule{bla}
\Rule{foo}
\section{Section}
\Rule{foobar}
\subsection{Subsection}
\Rule{yet another one}

\end{document}
```

The above setup of `\Rule` is a copy of `\section`, with all the required amenities.