# How to manually set section numbering in latex

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex, sections

I'm writing a book and it's divided in chapters and sections, but the will be some sections dedicated to math needed, so i would like to know if it's possible to label them with an M like this

1. **Chapter one title**

   1.1 First section

   1.2 Second section
2. **Chapter two title**

   M1 First math section

   ```
   M1.1  First math subsection
   ```

   2.1 First section

   M2 Second math section

And so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LaTeX: creating new section headings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081715/latex-creating-new-section-headings)

Comment: I assume you've just missed the sequential numbering, since the sections in chapter 2 should probably be numbered `M1`, `M1.1`, `M2`, `M2.1`, ...